# tooltip not showing on mouse enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm using qtip2 to display a tool tip from a link in a table, and i call it on mouse enter. The issue is the tool tip is not displaying but the the alert works and i cant figure out why the tool tip wont show. Thank you for any help.

```
$('#tblOrder tr td a').on('mouseenter',function(){


       alert('');

       var id = $('#tblOrder tr[id*="row"]').attr('id').substr(3);

          $(".proper a").qtip({

            content: {
            text: 'Loading.....',
                ajax: {
                url: '<%=Url.Action("Alarms") %>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id: id},
                success: function(data, status){
                    this.set('content.text', data);
                },
                error: function(xhr){
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log($('#tblOrder tr[id*="row"]').attr('id').substr(3));

                }
              }
            },
            show: {
        effect: function() {
            $(this).slideDown();
        }
    },
    hide: {
        effect: function() {
            $(this).slideUp();
        }
    }

            });

       });
```

I have created a jsfiddle to go with this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f0sbo0vd/2/)

Comment: Make a fiddle with your code :)

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f0sbo0vd/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/f0sbo0vd/3/

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#tblOrder tr a', function(event) {
    $(".proper a").qtip({        
         content: {
             text: 'Loading.....',
             ajax: {
                 url: '<%=Url.Action("Alarms") %>',
                 type: 'POST',

                 success: function (data, status) {
                     this.set('content.text', data);
                 },
                 error: function (xhr) {
                     console.log(xhr.responseText);                  
                 }
             }
         },
         show: {
             event: event.type,
             ready: true,
             effect: function () {
                 $(this).slideDown();
             }
         },
         hide: {
             effect: function () {
                 $(this).slideUp();
             }
         }

     }, event);

 });
```

### EDIT

To show qtip on the link use this http://jsfiddle.net/f0sbo0vd/5/

Just change

```
$(".proper a").qtip({ ... });
```

to

```
$(this).qtip({ ... });
```

Comment: Thank you, the only issue is it opens the tool tip for every link in my table how would i do this to only apply to the current link. sorry i realized i only had one link in the table on my fiddle but in the actual table there is a lot of them and this opens a tool tip for every row. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I figured it out thank you i just changed the selector $('.proper a') to $(this). thank you for your help.